# Truffle migrate is not deploying to Ganache

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

I tried command truffle migrate --reset, but it is unable to connect to Ganche
here is the error:
[image]

This is the code inside truufle-config.js file:
[image]

And these are the RPC server details:
[image]

Comment: You have a typo in truffle-config.js. Change post to port

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a typo in your `truffle-config.js`: `post` instead of `port`.

Try this out:

```js
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  },
```

Then:

- Double check the settings on Ganache match with the ones on `truffle-config.js`
- Check that Ganache is running.

And finally open a new terminal and run the following 2 commands **in the same folder where the file `truffle-config.js` is hosted**:

```sh
truffle console ––network development

migrate ––reset
```

Answer (score 1):

I face same problem but when change migration file name **"first.js" to "1_first.js" then it work for me**.
After that **if you face development failed error** then change version of solc compiler version 0.8.17 or lowest.

Comment: this was the case for me, very stupid thing to debug... thx

Comment: Why this solution works? It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
networks: {
    development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     
     port: 7545,            
     network_id: "*",       
    }
},
```

Open the terminal and run the following command in the same folder where the file truffle-config.js is hosted:

```
truffle console ––network development
```